# Bounded Infinite Set: Infinitely Many Points

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

How is it that if $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded infinite set, where $x=\sup(S)$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$?

Answer (score 9):

Take $S=(0,1)\cup \left\{ 2\right\}$.

Answer (score 3):

If the supremum $s$ does not belong to $S$, then it will be the limit point of $S$ which means that every neighborhood of $s$ contains infinitely many point of $S$. However this is not true if $s\in S$ in general. But if $S$ does not contain any isolated point, then all $p\in S$ is a limit point of $S$. Now supremum of a bounded set with no isolated point is its limit point and therefore it contains infinitely many points of $S$.

Comment: (+1) Or even more generally, if $\sup S\notin S,$ regardless of whether or not $S$ has isolated points.

Comment: Exactly that's for sure true. I will edit the answer.